# how to make customise header and footer from scratch in wordpress with elementor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i want to get customized header and footer for a website which i am suppose to make from scratch by elementor in wordpress. the menu should come directly in the header but it is showing some errors, like, "Hey, your current theme is not supported by Header Footer Elementor, click here to check out the supported themes."

Comment: Theme needs to support Header Footer to work properly. May be you need to find another theme. Or create child theme and implement the required support. You can check https://github.com/elementor/hello-theme

Comment: I am not working on any theme actually, I am making it from the scratch.

Comment: Ok. Check that sample Elementer theme. You can find there how you can implement Header and Footer.